# Full width span floating to right

Tags: html, css

i wonder how it is possible to have multiple spans inside a div, with the last span floating to the bottom right and taking all the remaining width in the "row".

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpakL/
The problem is, that the fullWidth span is not always at the bottom. You can resize your browser window to see the fullWidth span moving.

This is how it should look like:

[image: good]

This is how it shold not look like:

[image: bad]

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="item">sdfdsfsdf</span>
    <span class="item">sdfsdfsdfsdf</span>
    <span class="item">dsfdsfdsfsd</span>
    <span class="item">fsdfsdfsdffsdf</span>
    <span class="item">dsgsdf</span>
    <span class="item">dfd</span>
    <span class="item">fdfdf</span>
    <span class="itemFullWidth">FullWidth</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
}
.item {
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;

    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px; /* Vertically center */
    margin: 5px;
}

.itemFullWidth {
    background-color:green;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;

    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px; /* Vertically center */
    margin: 5px;

    min-width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pure css as you don't know what the remaining width is going to be

Comment: @squarebracket [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/gpakL/4/)?

Comment: @Vucko Not exactly, i would like to have the fullWidth box "in line" with the other spans.

Comment: @squarebracket the _width_ is the problem. You can put _media querys_ and for every break point put a different width that suits you. [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Answer (score 1):

If you open to use flexbox, it could be easily done [(WebKit demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrp72/1/):

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; /* allow multiple rows */
}

.container > :last-child {
    flex: 1; /* absorb remaining space */
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution! Working (with prefixed CSS) in Opera+Chrome. However, Safari and FF can't handle `flex-wrap: wrap;`. IE not tested. Unfortunately I cannot use your solution, because I need to support the above browsers. But it is definitely the way to go in the future! Also see http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ for creating flexbox CSS with prefixed CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a JavaScript/jQuery assisted solution for this problem.  In a more general case, there are jQuery packages like David DeSandro's Masonry or Packery or Isotope: http://desandro.com/

Here is my version of how you could do this using jQuery.

```
function resetEndItemWidth() {
    var wContainer = $(".container").width();

    var minWidthEndItem = parseInt($(".itemFullWidth").css("min-width"));

    var endItemMargins =  $(".itemFullWidth").outerWidth(true) 
                            - $(".itemFullWidth").outerWidth();

    var prevItemOffset = $(".itemFullWidth").prev().offset();
    var prevItemWidth = $(".itemFullWidth").prev().outerWidth(true);

    var freeWidth = wContainer - (prevItemWidth + prevItemOffset.left);
    if (freeWidth < minWidthEndItem) {
        newWidth = wContainer - endItemMargins;
    } else {
        newWidth = Math.max(minWidthEndItem,freeWidth);
    }

    $(".itemFullWidth").width(newWidth);
}

resetEndItemWidth();

$(window).resize(function(){resetEndItemWidth();});
```

See the demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/m6bx8/

**How This Works**

I look at the floated sibling before the last item (`.itemFullWidth`) and determine the amount of free space remaining on the line.

If there is enough free space, I reset the width of the full width item to fill the gap,
otherwise, the full width item is on a separate line and I set it to the width of the parent container.

For full width item (`.endItemMargins`), you need to account for the left-right margins and you need to get the minimum width from the `min-width` property.

The min-width requirement could be relaxed if you initialize the original with of the full width item.

**Other Comments**

The flex box solution is much more elegant.  However, it is good to have some options.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/gpakL/6/),

Using `position: relative;` for the container and `position: absolute;` for the 
`.itemFullWidth`, you can get it to work to some extent. You'll need some js I guess.

Comment: Please update the link to the fiddle, it's pointing to the unmodified fiddle from the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Simple jQuery solution, however CSS solutions should be preferred over JS solutions.

http://jsfiddle.net/A8mSu/

HTML:

```
<div class="container clearfix">
 <span class="item">sdfdsfsdf</span>
 <span class="item">sdfsdfsdfsdf</span>
 <span class="item">dsfdsfdsfsd</span>
 <span class="item">fsdfsdfsdffsdf</span>
 <span class="item">dsgsdf</span>
 <span class="item">dfd</span>
 <span class="item">fdfdf</span>
 <span class="item itemFullWidth">FullWidth</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function setWidth()
{
    $obj = $('.container .itemFullWidth');
    $obj.width('auto').width($obj.parent().width() - $obj.position().left);
}

$(window).resize(setWidth);
$(document).ready(setWidth);
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 50%;
}
.item {
    float: left;
    background-color: orange;

    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px; /* Vertically center */
    margin: 5px;
}
.itemFullWidth {
    background-color: green;
    min-width: 80px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try , Please Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/gpakL/14/

```
function findWidth (){
var ConWidth = $('.container').width();
var leftWidth = $('.container .item:last').offset().left
var lastItemWidth = $('.container .item:last').width();
var fixPos = ConWidth - (leftWidth + lastItemWidth)

$('.container .itemFullWidth').width(  fixPos -20  );
};

$(document).ready(function(){
findWidth();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    findWidth();   
});
```